# assigning pointers vs memcpy/memmove

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Hi there I have a question pertaining to C pointers (especially void *)

I'm working with void * pointers that point to arbitrary blobs of memory that act as cells for a Vector implementation. These blobs are allocated on the heap.

My question is why does assigning

```
    void *dest = CVectorNth(cv, i);
    void *src = CVectorNth(cv, i-1);
    *(void **)dest = *(void **)src;
```

not work while

```
    memmove(dest, src, elementSize);
```

does work.

Why do I need to use memmove? In my head I am changing the value of the pointer to the address the src is pointing to.

I know memmove is the correct way to go, but now I can't even think of a reason why

```
    dest = src;
```

wouldn't work

Comment: look here for deep copy [the diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811893/creating-a-copy-constructor-for-a-linked-list?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;` **!=** `memmove(dest, src, elementSize);`   first is just assignment operation where as `memmove()` copy memory content from `src` to `dest` (deep-copy)

**Edit**

Suppose, your `dest` and  `src` are something like this ?

```
  src           5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +----->| A|B |C | D |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+

  dest          18  19 20 21  
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 18  +----->|  |  |  |   |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
```

Now, what `*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;` ?

it like

```
  src           5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +----->| A|B |C | D |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+

  dest          18  19 20 21  
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 18  +----->| A|  |  |   |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
```

because by assignment you copy content (because using *) of location 5 into location 18.

<sub>Its rough diagram because `*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;` someting wrong in my understating</sub> 
consider larsmans's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710633/assigning-pointers-vs-memcpy-memmove/16710867#16710867)

Whereas, by doing `memmove(dest, src, elementSize);`:

it like

```
  src           5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +----->| A|B |C | D |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+

  dest          18  19 20 21  
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 18  +----->| A|B |C |   |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
```

Suppose `elementSize` = `3` ,

memmove copy `elementSize` elements from src to dest pointed memory area (deepcopy)

by `dest = src` do like:

```
  src           5   6  7  8    
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +----->| A|B |C | D |
  +-----+  --->+--+--+--+---+
           | 
  dest     |    18  19 20 21  
  +-----+  |   +--+--+--+---+
  | 5   +---   |  |  |  |   |
  +-----+      +--+--+--+---+
```

Shadow copy:

From: [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102380/thomas) (thanks!)

> More specifically, the latter technique is known as "pointer swapping"
>   and does have its uses, but is not directly compatible with deep
>   memory copy (it requires a different design, in particular the two
>   memory areas being "swapped" need to be persistent). For a vector
>   implementation it's unlikely to be of any us

Comment: More specifically, the latter technique is known as "pointer swapping" and does have its uses, but is not directly compatible with deep memory copy (it requires a different design, in particular the two memory areas being "swapped" need to be persistent). For a vector implementation it's unlikely to be of any use.

Comment: Awesome diagrams. Thanks Grijesh, these really helped

Answer (score 4):

```
*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;
```

interprets both, `dest` and `src`, as pointers to `void*`, and copies `sizeof(void *)` bytes from where `src` points to to where `dest` points to.

```
memmove(dest, src, elementSize);
```

moves `elementSize` bytes from where `src` points to to where `dest` points to. If perchance `elementSize == sizeof(void *)`, both will have the same effect if the regions affected do not overlap and both `src` and `dest` are suitably aligned. The first will invoke undefined behaviour if either of `dest` and `src` is not properly aligned (if the affected regions overlap, at least one will probably not be properly aligned).

If you have a specific `Element` type, you just need to cast `dest` and `src` to the proper type,

```
*(Element *)dest = *(Element *)src;
```

to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I am big fan of your answers

Answer (score 1):

This is because C follows a design philosophy that boils down to "you don't pay for what you don't need, and you don't get want you don't ask for". In particular, when you declare a variable to have type `void*`, then you request a pointer that can point to anything, and what you get is *only* such a pointer; not a pointer + a type field + a size field for the thing pointed to, so the compiler doesn't know how many bytes you intend to copy.

Note that

```
dest = src;
```

does *work*, it just doesn't do what you expect. It reassigns `dest` to point to the same thing as `src`, meaning you now have two names for the same thing (and possibly a memory leak). That can be quite useful (except the leak), but it's a very shallow copy.

As for

```
*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;
```

That's undefined behavior in most cases. When it does work, it takes `src` to actually be a pointer to `void*` and assigns this to the `void*` pointed to by `dest`, so it's still a pointer copy, though an indirect one.

Comment: @sbjluke: you know, but the compiler doesn't know because it has type `void*`. That's the C type that can point to anything: a `FILE`, a `const int **const *`, a `struct foo[4]`.

Comment: Okay I understand that now, thanks. So why doesn't dest = src work for me. I understand that it is a shallow copy, but passing around pointers to memory on the stack seems like it should work.

Comment: Thanks! you are correct `*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;` is undefined behavior.. I was unconfined to write this..

Comment: I figured it out. It's in the fact that the way the vector works as an array I can't change the value of the pointer. I must change the value of what it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 pointers you could do something like:

```
*(char*) dest = *(char*) src;
*(double*) dest = *(double*) src;
*(struct{char[50] a;}*) dest = *(struct{char[50] a;}*) src;
```

Equivalent to:

```
memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(char));
```

But unfortunately a pointer in C does not know about its allocated size. Via its type one knows about its element size, but any array size is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(void **)dest = *(void **)src;
```

says

treat dest and src *as if they were* a pointer to a `void *`, and copy that `void *` from `*src` to `*dst`.

This results in copying `sizeof(void *)` bytes, which may be more or less than your `elementSize` (the result might .

(It is not clear from your sample What CVectorNth does, what's the effet of its parameters, or what the actual underlying data structure).

Answer (score 0):

A call to `memmove()` implies the effective copy of memory from one position to another one. Whenever the size of the memory copied is correct, the call will always work.

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;

memmove( &x, &y, sizeof( int ) );
```

...and this is exactly what's missing in your first code. The pointer to void, `void *`, is a way to point to any variable, whichever its type is. This implies there is no inherent size information when dealing with `void *` pointers (because different types have different sizes).

For example:

```
int x = 5;
int * ptr = &x;
```

In this code, `ptr` carries two informations: the address in which `x` is stored, and that the information there spans for four bytes in a 32 bits system (8 bytes in a 64 bits one), i.e., the result of `sizeof(int)`. Therefore, this will work:

```
*ptr = 11;
```

...because the system knows where to store the rvalue (11), and in how many bytes.

So, in order for the first code to work, we should write instead something like (provided the type of the elements of the vector is `int`, and that I understand what `CVectorNth` does):

```
*( (int *) dest ) = *( (int *) src );
```

Anyway, this won't exactly work if the element of the vector contains pointers to memory in the heap, for example. Well, you'd be copying the pointers, but not the content itself pointed by them. If you don't keep this in mind, you'll probably find yourself with unwanted surprises.

Hope this helps.