# How to create and execute a copy constructor for a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

I have tried looking at videos and older posts but it is still very difficult to understand the concept of copy constructors. Would someone clear it up for me? My class did not really cover this part 100% my professor focused mainly on constructors and destructors.

**Main CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    node access;

    access.getData();
    access.outData();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Header File**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    node(); // Had to create my own default constructor because of my copy constructor.
    node(const node &n); // This is a copy constructor.
    ~node();
    void getData();
    void outData();
private:
    int num;
    int lCount = 0; // Counts the number of nodes, increments after each user input.
    int *ptr; // Where the linked list will be copied into
    node *next;
    node *first;
    node *temp;
    node *point;
};

node::node()
{
    num = 0;
}

node::node(const node &n)
{
    temp = first;

    ptr = new node;
    for (int i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = temp->num;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

node::~node() // Deletes the linked list.
{
    while (first != NULL)
    {
        node *delP = first; // Creates a pointer delP pointing to the first node.
        first = first->next; // "Removes first node from the list and declares new first.
        delete delP; // Deletes the node that was just removed.
    }
    cout << "List deleted" << endl;
}

void node::getData() // Simple function that creates a linked list with user input.
{
    int input = 0;
    point = new node;
    first = point;
    temp = point;

    while (input != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter any integer, -1 to end." << endl;
        cin >> input;

        if (input == -1)
        {
            point->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            lCount++;
            point->num = input;
            temp = new node;
            point->next = temp;
            point = temp;
        }
    }
}

void node::outData()
{
    temp = first;
    cout << "Original" << endl;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->num << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    cout << "Copied" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

This little snippet is what I am having trouble with in particular:

```
node::node(const node &n)
{
    temp = first;

    ptr = new node;
    for (int i = 0; i < lCount; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = temp->num;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a copy constructor for a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811893/creating-a-copy-constructor-for-a-linked-list)

Comment: @JasonC I have looked through that already, also previous posts. I just don't understand looking at someone else's code. I am hoping that having my own code to look at will clear it up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was tinkering with a much simpler copy constructor. I was having trouble understanding syntax, everything was very complicated and it was overwhelming to look at.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    node(int x); // Normal Construtor
    node(const node &cpy); // Copy Constructor
    void change(); // Changes data value
    void outData();
private:
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    node var1(123);
    var1.outData();
    node var2 = var1;
    var2.outData();

    var2.change();
    var1.outData();
    var2.outData();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

node::node(int x)
{
    data = x;
}

node::node(const node &cpy)
{
    data = cpy.data;
}

void node::outData()
{
    cout << data << endl;
}

void node::change()
{
    int userIn;
    cin >> userIn;
    data = userIn;
}
```

Output:

```
123
123
```

(input: 4444)

Output:

```
123
4444
```